# New page to same page scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a link `$("#english")` that opens a new page, I am using the code below to make the new page go to the same page scroll position as where the previous page (with the link in it) was.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('scroll'))  
    {
        window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scroll")));

    }



        $("#english").on("click",function()
        {
             localStorage.setItem("scroll", document.body.scrollTop);
        });

window.localStorage.clear();
```

Using Safari as a browser this works well, but with FireFox the new page starts at the top op the page and does NOT go to the same page scroll position. Anyone, please? How can I make this cross browser proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is firefox returns 0 for `document.body.scrollTop`.
Instead, Firefox wants you to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, which - however - does not work Safari.

There is a multitude of possible properties that work in some browsers and not in others.

In my experience `window.pageYOffset` works best (IE>=9)

Comment: Jayms, fantastic, thanks for sharing!!  It works om my safari and FireFox now. So a list of browser variables are required? How would I go about that?

Comment: a common way is to chain them with a logical OR, like `var y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || ...` But really, you should be fine with `pageYOffset`

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code that works (thanks to Jayms):

```
<script>

/*makes a new page jump to same scroll position as the scroll position when the link is activated*/ 

if(localStorage.getItem('scroll'))  
        {
            window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scroll")));

        }

$("#englishflag").on("click",function()
{
     localStorage.setItem("scroll", window.pageYOffset);
});


 window.localStorage.clear();

  /*END*/ 
</script>
```